# vim: disable multi-line command input

Tags: vim

When using vim, sometimes I end up in a state where entered commands (ones which are preceded by a : colon) are put in some kind of secondary buffer instead of being executed, and I have to exit from this mode first (by using :q?) to be able to return to editing of the original file. Sometimes all my previous input ends up pasted in the file I was editing.

I don't know why this feature is here, but I'm pretty sure I never need it, so is there a way to turn it completely so that it will never happen? I just need this third mode ever.

Comment: This functionality exists so that you can copy-and-paste into the command-line buffer and you can edit it using normal commands.  I find the former to be especially useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you may be accidentally brining up the command-line window. One is you are already in :-command line and accidentally press `<c-f>`. The other is you are accidentally typing `q:` in normal mode.

To disable the first:

```
:cnoremap <c-f> <nop>
```

To disable the second:

```
:nnoremap q: <nop>
```

Comment: So if you mess up the key order typing the ":q", you get even deeper into the VIM. Makes it more understandable why people keep googling how to exit VIM.